# Why does a Memento object have a setState() function?

Tags: memento

This is the one thing I don't understand about this pattern. Why doesn't a Memento object just have a constructor and getState() method? When does it make sense to set the Memento's state after creating it? Isn't that like changing the past?

Comment: The Wikipedia example (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern), has it implemented with only a constructor and a getState.

Comment: Hm, thanks for that, most examples and explanations I'm seeing include a setState function

Comment: Interesting point! Perhaps it's from the habit of having both get, set accessors. In which case the set should be private

Answer (score 0):

You should not have setState method in Memento class. It makes no sense. Memento is just a token that Caretaker keeps to restore the state of Originator. If Caretaker wants a new Memento with new state information it should get it from Originator.

[Here is a good example.](http://www.brownfort.com/2015/01/memento-design-pattern-ruby/)